# How do I import a module or project to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm specifically trying to import this library/module/project http://viewpagerindicator.com but I can't find an **"import module"** option, just a **"new module"**. I have searched already and all I find is people saying "import module already works since 0.5" but it doesn't shows how to do it. Can anybody guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use maven repository to include **ViewpagerIndicator** in your module's dependencies.

This is what you need to add in to dependencies section of your module's **`build.gradle`** file

```
dependencies {
  .......
  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
}
```

sync project with gradle after adding the same and that's it, Now you are good to go to use ViewPagerIndicator in your project without taking much headache.

Comment: yeah I ended up doing this yesterda, the thing is the repository didn't appear on the list at first, so that's why I tried to add it externally

Comment: So is it working fine now or do you need any more help ? The same thing is working fine for me .

Answer (score 0):

I just opened my Android Studio, and I have an "Import Project" and "Import Module" under the File menu.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't add it to my project, it just creates a new project.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't add the library to my project, it just opens it in another window, I cannot use it

Comment: So you're trying to add an external library? Try right clicking on "External Libraries" and choosing "new"

Comment: `External Libraries -> New` appears gray, can't click it. Do I have a wrong setting maybe?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why yours would be grey. Perhaps ask a new question with a more specific title pertaining to adding external libraries.